# Save dropdownlist state after form submit in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a form and Html.DropDownList in it. After the form submit, dropdownlist state is changing to default. How can I maintain dropdownlist state after form submit?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Result", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Form" }))
           {
             @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DropList, new[] { 
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "first", Value = "first"}, 
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "second", Value = "second"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "third", Value = "third"} 
                }, "DefaultState")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show controller's part that is responsible for form's post handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant. Unless if after submit, you are passing back the model into the view. Why would you like to do that? Because after a form submit, the form should reset and get ready for another data entry session, no?

Comment: I know this is quite late, but i struggeling at the same point ATM. I want to keep the information selects, if validation errors accour.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Selected property of SelectListItem

Also, make sure the value of Model.DropList is set in your controller from the post.

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("List", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Form" }))
       {
         @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DropList, new[] { 
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "first", Value = "first", Selected = Model.DropList == "first"}, 
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "second", Value = "second", Selected = Model.DropList == "second"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "third", Value = "third", Selected = Model.DropList == "third"} 
            }, "DefaultState")
```

Comment: That depends on whether you are model binding or not.  If you have the model passed as a parameter of the action method (and assuming it is binding correctly) then you need to make sure the model is being passed to the view. Otherwise, you will need to get the value for DropList and set the DropList property on your model (again, passing the model to the view)

Comment: It might be worth you posting your controller action method as @Andrei suggests

Comment: Is DropList a property of LinksListViewModel?  If so, then you need to add the line `DropList = DropList` afther `Type = DropList`